# HTML with hidden password

Tags: html, security

I want to create an html that ultimately will be sent as an email. The email will have a password but hidden. The email will have something like a submit button. On click of that, the hidden password should be fetched and sent in a POST request. How can I have a hidden password underneath the submit button

I have HTML like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            Username: <input type="text" name="usrname"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't submit html forms in an email. Check https://mailchimp.com/en/help/limitations-of-html-email/ for what you can or cannot do in an email.

Comment: Generate the password on the server.

Comment: it's better to store the password in a db table and use an id in the email with a url that looks like `/email/url?id=4` where you'd use the id to get the data from the db as @QuentinHayot says, this can't be done in email

Comment: No sane email client will execute JavaScript code found in a message so the only conceivable way to encrypt it would be a dedicated mail encryption protocol like PGP. Whatever, emailing passwords is a bad idea in general. What do you need this for? Can't you just generate one-time login tokens?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález by one time token , u mean OTP? For this I will have to enter the otp additionally which I do not want to.. Here i am talking about some token being sent programmatically in the mail body. and when submited, the program should authenticate the person therefore using the token. this token will be distroyed immediately. But it is very important to keep it safe until then. Do you have a better approach?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dont put forms in emails. Putting forms in emails is bad.

Comment: it's for a email .. you can't have forms in email

Comment: ah yeah - i totally mis-read the question. You are right, don't put forms in emails.

Comment: you should let OP know as they've marked this as accepted which could lead to all sorts of issues :)

Answer (score 0):

try this you can fetch password using email and passing to input field

```
<input id="prodId" name="prodId" type="hidden" value="xm234jq">
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="hidden" value="thepassword">
```

however if this really is a "password" i would not recommend this as anyone can just inspect the code and find it even if it is visually hidden. if it is not a "secret password" more like an identifier tag or something, then this works fine though.

Comment: it's for a email .. you can't have forms in email

Comment: it is about programmatically sending an email .. Can I not send body as html in the email?